# Joining multiple fields to one field and displaying data

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a Crystal Reports report, and I have on table which had 4 tables

[UserInfo],
ID1,
ID2,
ID3,
ID4

And a second table that has a:

IDType,
Description,
Name

I need to join the IDs from table 1 into IDType so I can display the Name in the report. If I link ID1 and IDType with an Inner Join I can get the data I need, but if I link any of the others IDs with IDType all data stops loading altogeter. If I use a Left Outer join for the links, then some data is displayed, but not the Name of the ID. Not every user has data in ID2, ID3 or ID4 as those are optional (so, some values are NULL). How can I work with this? I have been breaking my head for two days and no go. I am using CR11. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you've got one table (UserInfo) with 4 separate left outer joins to 4 distinct copies of the IDType table, yes? If that's the case then there is no reason that the ID names wouldn't display as long as their corresponding ID wasn't null.

Comment: That's the problem... they aren't showing! If I link ID1 and IDType, I can get Name an Description to show in the report. ID1 is never null. If I link ID2 with IDType, then the Name and Description is shown as a Blank space for either ID1's and ID2's fields. I have no idea why this is happening, and I also selected "Select Distinct" just in case.

Comment: Have you tried running this query directly on the DB? Can you post a picture of your table joins?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but...
Have you tried on adding the same table again?

It'll create an alias for that table. 
Say the second table is named as '**details**'.

In your case, you need to **add the 'details' table for four(4) times**.

Then link the IDType of the first '**details**' table to **ID1**
...Then
IDtype of the second '**details**' table to **ID2**.
And so on...